# SQL query help - function with 2 nested conditional statements

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write a SQL function but an having problems with getting 2 nested conditions to work.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_HasAcceptedPolicyDate(@employeeid smallint, @policyid int)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
--If policy is required
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fn_getEmployeePolicies(@employeeid) AS EmployeePolicies WHERE EmployeePolicies.PolicyId=@policyid)
    SELECT 
    CASE 
    WHEN (convert(varchar,MAX(HasAcceptedPolicyDate),103)) IS Null then 'NOT ACCEPTED'  
    else convert(varchar,MAX(HasAcceptedPolicyDate),103) 
    end 
    AS 'HasAcceptedPolicyDate'
    FROM policysignoff.EmployeePolicy
    WHERE EmployeeId = @employeeid
    AND PolicyId = @policyid

--If policy is not required
ELSE 
    RETURN "NOT REQUIRED"
END
GO
```

The logic I am trying to build in is:
1. given an employeeId and a PolicyId, return the date that policy was accepted.
2. If the policy was no required for that person then return "Not Required" (I am using another function to check this hence the IF EXISTS)
3. Is the policy was not accepted then return "Not accepted" (instead of just displaying NULL).

The problem i am having is that I can't find a way to get condition 2 working i.e. the IF exists.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add BEGIN and END around you inner statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER FUNCTION fn_HasAcceptedPolicyDate(@employeeid smallint, @policyid int)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
--If policy is required
DECLARE @ReturnValue nvarchar(max) ='NOT REQUIRED'
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM fn_getEmployeePolicies(@employeeid) AS EmployeePolicies WHERE EmployeePolicies.PolicyId=@policyid)
BEGIN   SELECT @ReturnValue =
    CASE 
    WHEN (convert(varchar,MAX(HasAcceptedPolicyDate),103)) IS Null then 'NOT ACCEPTED'  
    else convert(varchar,MAX(HasAcceptedPolicyDate),103) 
    end     
    FROM policysignoff.EmployeePolicy
    WHERE EmployeeId = @employeeid
    AND PolicyId = @policyid
--    return @ReturnValue
END
--If policy is not required
return @ReturnValue
END
GO
```